# Pure css Chessboard with div & no classes or ids, is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout

```html
<div id="chess">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make a chess board using only css and without changing the above html? That means no classes or ids.
I've been searching for ideas an such for 2 days now. I tried with nth-child() and some variations but no success.

I am awfully curious if this can be done. It was given as an assignment to someone.

So please, any ideas?

Comment: which browser and version do you want to support?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't have to hardcode each `:nth-child()`. Here's one way to shorten it. Each selector corresponds to a row on the chessboard:

```
#chess div:nth-child(-2n+8), 
#chess div:nth-child(8) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+15), 
#chess div:nth-child(16) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+24),
#chess div:nth-child(24) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+31),
#chess div:nth-child(32) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+40),
#chess div:nth-child(40) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+47),
#chess div:nth-child(48) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+56),
#chess div:nth-child(56) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+63) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2knX8)

Comment: +1 for the shorthand! I would love a bit of an explanation to this as I've never seen this syntax. Although I **believe** your board is rotated 90 degrees (or mirror imaged) and that the top/left bottom/right squares should be black

Comment: Meh. I haven't played chess in years ([Wikipedia does lay out its chessboards with the white squares on the top left and bottom right corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard)), and I kinda prefer @Christoph's solution as it doesn't make use of ugly negatives or combinators.

Comment: @Dutchie432: A negative `n` causes it to count backwards, so for `:nth-child(-an+b)` you grab only the first `b` elements at multiples of `a`. Similarly for `:nth-last-child(-an+b)`, you grab only the last `b` elements at multiples of `a`.

Answer (score 27):

This is an interesting problem. I think a chess board is better expressed as a table than as a series of divs, as a screen reader would dictate the rows and columns where the figures are located. With a table:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kWJZ/

Comment: Normally I would rat on somebody for changing the HTML, but this is such an appropriate use of a table that I just have to upvote instead :)

Comment: The color trick (using parent too for odd even counting) was mind blowing.

Answer (score 22):

The following approach makes use of the fact that the coloring pattern repeats every 16 squares (counting from top left to bottom right). So, the first rule `#chess div:nth-child(16n+1)` colors the squares 1,17,33 and 49 (in other words, "the first column"). This is repeated with additional rules for all colored squares from 3 to 16 each representing a separate column.

With the given markup, it doesn't matter if you use `nth-of-type` or `nth-child`, however with additional markup it might, so `nth-child` is kind of the more obvious choice.

```js
for(i=0;i<64;i++){chess.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))}
```

```css
#chess div{
     width:22px;height:22px;border:1px solid black;
     float:left; 
}

#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+16),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+14),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+12),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+10),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+7),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+5),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+3),
#chess div:nth-of-type(16n+1){   
    background-color:black;
}

#chess div:nth-of-type(8n+1){   
    clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="chess"></div>
```

Comment: +1, I was doing this earlier too, based on an [old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3557848/94197), using `nth-child` instead of `nth-of-type`.

Comment: +1 super elegant. Took me a bit to get the logic behind this: `Select the 8 divs (hence 8 selectors) to be colored in the first two rows (2 rows = 16 divs) and repeat ruleset every 16 divs` I didn't see a good reason to use nth-of-type, though, and I flipped the order because it just makes more sense to me. Great job.

Comment: @philtune Thanks for your input, I appreciate it! I adjusted my answer accordingly, and hope it is more useful now.

Answer (score 4):

In pure CSS, the accepted answer looks right - however, if you want to shorten this up with SCSS, you can do some maths:

```css
#chess {
  div {
    background: #fff;
    /* even children on odd rows, odd children on even rows */
    @each $offset in 2 4 6 8 9 11 13 15 {
      &:nth-child(16n + #{$offset}) {
        background: #000;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

of course it can be done...

```
body {
    background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 75%, #000 75%, #000 100%);
    -moz-background-size:100px 100px;
    background-size:100px 100px;
    -webkit-background-size:101px 101px;
    background-position:0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `nth-child(odd)` or `nth-child(even)` to colour the squares, because not all the "odd" or "even" squares are the same colour. Counting from the top-left as position "1", the first row's white squares would be 1, 3, 5, 7. Continuing into the second row, the white squares would be 10, 12, 14, 16. The third row would be back to odd numbers, 17, 19, 21, and 23.

You could therefore *manually* colour each of the squares as follows:

```
#chess {
    /* 8 squares at 30x30px per square */
    width: 240px;
    height:240px;
    background:#000;
}

#chess div {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
}

#chess div:nth-child(1), /* first row */
#chess div:nth-child(3),
#chess div:nth-child(5),
#chess div:nth-child(7),
#chess div:nth-child(10), /* second row */
#chess div:nth-child(12),
#chess div:nth-child(14),
#chess div:nth-child(16)
/* ... up to 64 ... */
{
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @Christoph: You can get creative with arithmetic operations, but you can't use `odd` or `even`.

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm late to the game, and there are already several good answers to this question.

I'd just like to add a solution I find easy to manage when dealing with advanced `:nth-child` selectors. It's somewhat verbose and not as elegant as a few other suggestions, but I find it easy to read and deal with.

By chaining the `:nth-child` pseudo classes you can limit your selection to certain ranges only. In pseudo code it can be laid out as:

```
:nth-child( start of range ):nth-child( children to select ):nth-child( end of range )
```

This can be used to color the chess board row by row like this:

```css
/* Start at 1st square, color odd squares until the 8th */
#chess :nth-child(n+1):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+8),

/* Even squares from 9th to 16th */
#chess :nth-child(n+9):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+16),

/* Odd squares from 17th to 24th */
#chess :nth-child(n+17):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+24),

/* Even squares from 25th to 32nd */
#chess :nth-child(n+25):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+32),

/* Odd squares from 33rd to 40th */
#chess :nth-child(n+33):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+40),

/* Even squares from 41st to 48th */
#chess :nth-child(n+41):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+48),

/* Odd squares from 49th to 56th */
#chess :nth-child(n+49):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+56),

/* Even squares from 57th to 64th */
#chess :nth-child(n+57):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+64) {
    background: #000;
}
```

```css
#chess {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#chess div {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
}

#chess :nth-child(n+1):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+8),
#chess :nth-child(n+9):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+16),
#chess :nth-child(n+17):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+24),
#chess :nth-child(n+25):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+32),
#chess :nth-child(n+33):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+40),
#chess :nth-child(n+41):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+48),
#chess :nth-child(n+49):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+56),
#chess :nth-child(n+57):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+64) {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="chess">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
table.CHESS {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.CHESS td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid gray 1px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #000;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the area have the same dimension so you can consider a gradient coloration on the parent element

```css
#chess {
  /* define the size */
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /* define the grid */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  /* define the coloration */
  background:
   repeating-conic-gradient(white 0 25%,black 0 50%)
   0 0/calc(100%/4) calc(100%/4);

  
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="chess">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the best way to go as of 2023. If I may suggest two improvements, I assume it is safe to put `25%` directly instead of `calc(100%/4)`. And as the grid template declarations are equal they can be declared on one line using the `grid-template` shorthand :o)

Answer (score 0):

Done. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/LFVQU/1/

```html
<style type="text/css">
    #chess{
     width:800px;   
     height:800px;
     border:1px;
     border:1px solid #999;
    }
    #chess div{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;  
     float:left;  
    }
#chess div{background: #fff}
#chess div:nth-child(1), #chess div:nth-child(3), #chess div:nth-child(5), #chess div:nth-child(7),
#chess div:nth-child(10), #chess div:nth-child(12), #chess div:nth-child(14), #chess div:nth-child(16),
#chess div:nth-child(17), #chess div:nth-child(19), #chess div:nth-child(21), #chess div:nth-child(23),
#chess div:nth-child(26), #chess div:nth-child(28), #chess div:nth-child(30), #chess div:nth-child(32),
#chess div:nth-child(33), #chess div:nth-child(35), #chess div:nth-child(37), #chess div:nth-child(39),
#chess div:nth-child(42), #chess div:nth-child(44), #chess div:nth-child(46), #chess div:nth-child(48),
#chess div:nth-child(49), #chess div:nth-child(51), #chess div:nth-child(53), #chess div:nth-child(55),
#chess div:nth-child(58), #chess div:nth-child(60), #chess div:nth-child(62), #chess div:nth-child(64)
{
    background-color:#000;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#chess {width:256px; height:256px; border:1px solid;}  
#chess div {width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block; }
#chess div:nth-child(16n+1), #chess div:nth-child(16n+3),
#chess div:nth-child(16n+5), #chess div:nth-child(16n+7),
#chess div:nth-child(16n+10),#chess div:nth-child(16n+12),
#chess div:nth-child(16n+14),#chess div:nth-child(16n+16) {
  background-color:black;
}
```

I think answers using float/clear are better, just what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need a CSS3 chess board with each square having an id so that you can use it with JavaScript, I can propose this solution:

https://github.com/vpcom/CSS3-Chess-Board

A demo is available here: http://vincentperrin.com/cr/css3/css3-chess-board/

It's done with Sass (SCSS notation) but you can use the processed CSS file also available. For those who like, this kind of things can also be done with Jade.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If using 2 overlapped containers is acceptable, I think there is a more straightforward and "static" approach without using fancy css features:

```css
.chess {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
}

#up > div {
  height: 50px;
  width:  50px;
  margin: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#down > div {
  height: 50px;
  width:  50px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id = "cont">
  <div id = "up" class="chess">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

  </div>
  <div id = "down" class="chess">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by BoltClocks fiddle

```js
for(i=0;i<64;i++){chess.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))}
```

```css
#chess {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 2px solid #808080;
}
#chess div {
    float: left;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    background-color: #000;
}
#chess div:nth-child(8n+5){
  margin-left: 0;
}
#chess div:nth-child(32) ~ div{  /* we dont need those :D*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="chess"></div>
```

Probably my favorite one, using grid:

```js
for(i=0;i<64;i++){chess.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))}
```

```css
#chess {
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  place-items: stretch;
}

#chess div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #000;
}

/* swapping these 2 rules greatly helps understanding */
#chess div:nth-child(9n+1) {
  /* background-color:red; */
  grid-row-start: 8;
}
```

```html
<div id="chess"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="chess" -data-rows="8" -data-cols="8">
  
</div>
<style>
.chess {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:max-content;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: fit-content;
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}
.column {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.column:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.column:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #000;
}
</style>
<script>
const chessContainer = document.querySelector(".chess");
const rows = +chessContainer.getAttribute("-data-rows");
const cols = +chessContainer.getAttribute("-data-cols");
for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  const row = document.createElement("div");
  row.setAttribute("class", "row");
  for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    const column = document.createElement("div");
    column.setAttribute("class", "column");
    row.appendChild(column);
  }
  chessContainer.appendChild(row);
}

</script>
```

https://codepen.io/yogi-dad/pen/mdzPRzp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Let me suggest you more clean css:

```
.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(even), .divTableRow:nth-child(even) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #999;
    }
```

```css
.divTableRow:nth-child(odd) .divTableCell:nth-child(even), .divTableRow:nth-child(even) .divTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #999;
}

.divTable {
    display: table;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    height: 12.5%;
    width: 12.5%;
    text-align: center;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    background: white;
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
   <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-rock1" class="draggable black">♜</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-knight1" class="draggable black">♞</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-bishop1" class="draggable black">♝</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-queen" class="draggable black">♛</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-king" class="draggable black">♚</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-bishop2" class="draggable black">♝</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-knight2" class="draggable black">♞</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-rack2" class="draggable black">♜</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn1" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn2" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn3" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn4" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn5" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn6" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn7" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="black-pawn8" class="draggable black">♟</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn1" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn2" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn3" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn4" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn5" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn6" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn7" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-pawn8" class="draggable white">♙</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-rock1" class="draggable white">♖</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-knight1" class="draggable white">♘</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-bishop1" class="draggable white">♗</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-queen" class="draggable white">♕</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-king" class="draggable white">♔</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-bishop2" class="draggable white">♗</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-knight2" class="draggable white">♘</div>
         </div>
         <div class="divTableCell">
            <div id="white-rack2" class="draggable white">♖</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```