# PHP chessboard how to change colors?

Tags: php

I am very new when it come's to PHP
I need to make a chessboard for school.
I am using options to let them select the color of the board.
What i have so far is that 1 half is white always.
But where i'm stuck is how can i make PHP reconize the color they selected and make the chessboard that color.
I also am not sure if i need to use CSS with it please help me i'm stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Schaakbord</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schaakbord.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <select name="kleuren">
                <option name="kleur" value="geel">Geel</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="rood">Rood</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="blauw">Blauw</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="groen">Groen</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="paars">Paars</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="roze">Roze</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="bruin">Bruin</option>                       
                <option name="kleur" value="oranje">Oranje</option>             
                <option name="kleur" value="wit">Wit</option>
                <option name="kleur" value="grijs">Grijs</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <br/>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
                echo "<table>";
                for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($u=0;$u<8;$u++)
                    {
                        if(($i + $u)%2 == 0o)
                        {
                            echo "<td></td>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<th></th>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>


body    {
    background-color:black;
}
td  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
th  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: 1. `td` and `th` not aliases for eachother, use `<td class="black">` `<td class="white">` 2. `0o` is typo in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Schaakbord</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schaakbord.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="kleuren">
        <option name="kleur" value="yellow">Geel</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="red">Rood</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="blue">Blauw</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="green">Groen</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="purple">Paars</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="pink">Roze</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="brown">Bruin</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="orange">Oranje</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="with">Wit</option>
        <option name="kleur" value="gray">Grijs</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
 <br/>
<?php
     if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
           echo "<table>";
           for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
           {
              echo "<tr>";
              for($u=0;$u<8;$u++)
              {
                 if(($i + $u)%2 == 0)
                 {
                   echo "<td style='background-color:".$_GET["kleuren"]."'></td>";
                 }
                 else {
                     echo "<th></th>";
                 }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
     }
    echo "</table>";
 }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting the board into `<td>` and `<th>` use a class:

```
if(($i + $u)%2 == 0)
{
    echo "<td class="color"></td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td class="white"></td>";
}
```

Then in your css, change the color based on class:

```
td {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
}
td.color {
   background-color: <?php echo $GET['kleur'];?>;
}
td.white {
   background-color: white;
}
```

**Note**: The values set by the option elements would need to be valid css colors

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you use a css classname selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

You can also use even and odd selectors: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Example here: [Pure css Chessboard with div & no classes or ids, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114520/pure-css-chessboard-with-div-no-classes-or-ids-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class for each color, named like the color, and use the class after submitting.

**CSS**

```
body    {
    background-color:black;
}
td  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
th  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:white;
}

.white { background-color:white; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.....
```

Table

```
                $color = $_GET["kleuren"];
                for($u=0;$u<8;$u++)
                {
                    if(($i + $u)%2 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "<td class='".$class."'></td>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<th></th>";
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this way, As I did you can add more colors(HEX Values)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Schaakbord</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="schaakbord.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <select name="kleuren">
                <option value="#8B0000">Red</option>
                <option value="#483D8B">Blue</option>
                <option value="#228B22">Green</option>
                <option value="#FF69B4">Pink</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <br/>
        <?php
                echo "<table>";
                for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($u=0;$u<8;$u++)
                    {
                        if(($i + $u)%2 == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<td class='color'></td>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<td class='white'></th>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
    $color = $_GET['kleuren'];
}else{
    $color = "red";
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
body    {
    background-color:black;
}
.color  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>;
}
.white  {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:white;
}

</style>
```