# Creating 8x8 chessboard with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with colouring the right chessboard items. I want to have a white square at the beginning of every odd row but I'm struggling to do that with CSS. And also, I HAVE to this with flexbox.

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/diana-larussa/pen/OJRqwpy

I tried to do sth like that but it doesn't work.

```
        .container:nth-child(2n+1) .box:nth-child(2n) {
            background-color: black;
        }
```

```
This also doesn't work how I want it to:
```

```
     div:nth-child(even) {
         background-color: black;
     }
     
     div:nth-child(odd){
         background-color: white;
     }
```

Comment: is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114520/pure-css-chessboard-with-div-no-classes-or-ids-is-it-possible

Comment: Hmm, yeah, this is working: 
```        main div:nth-child(-2n+8), 
        main div:nth-child(8) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+15), 
        main div:nth-child(16) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+24),
        main div:nth-child(24) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+31),
        main div:nth-child(32) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+40),
        main div:nth-child(40) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+47),
        main div:nth-child(48) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+56),
        main div:nth-child(56) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+63) {
            background-color: #000;
        }```
But I am wondering if there's an easier solution....

Comment: I think it's better to use class

Comment: It's a lot of typing. I have an emmet extension. Is there some kind of shorthand to have 64 divs and then every 2 classes it changes to class "white" and then "black" for example?

Answer (score 0):

It works on my device. But I think it's better to use class.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  body {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: hotpink;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
  }

  .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 45vw;
      height: 45vw;
  }

  div {
      flex-basis: 12.5%;
      height: 12.5%;
  }
.box{
  background-color:#fff
}

.box:nth-child(-2n+8), 
.box:nth-child(8) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+15), 
.box:nth-child(16) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+24),
.box:nth-child(24) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+31),
.box:nth-child(32) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+40),
.box:nth-child(40) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+47),
.box:nth-child(48) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+56),
.box:nth-child(56) ~ div:nth-child(-2n+63) {
background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
  <main class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
  </main>
```

Comment: you took the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9114896/8620333

Comment: so I post the example of using class

Answer (score 0):

this is example of using class

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: hotpink;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 45vw;
    height: 45vw;
}

div {
    flex-basis: 12.5%;
    height: 12.5%;
}

.black {

    background-color: #000;

}
.white {

    background-color: #fff;
 
}
```

```html
 <main class="container">
   <!-- 1st -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 2nd -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <!-- 3th -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 4st -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <!-- 5th -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 6th -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <!-- 7th -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 8th -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    </div>
 </main>
```