# How can I select odd elements in odd flex rows with wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to solve [a CSS battle](https://cssbattle.dev/play/18).

[image]

As you can see odd elements in odd rows and even elements in even rows are orange. How can I do that without manually selecting elements like this:

```css
div:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(3n),
div:nth-of-type(8),
div:nth-of-type(11) {
  background: #F09462;
}
```

Here is my solution, but on bigger amount of elements it wouldn't work.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #5C434C;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(3n),
div:nth-of-type(8),
div:nth-of-type(11) {
  background: #F09462;
}

div,
div:last-of-type {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F5D6B4;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Could I possibly do that without using separate divs for rows, grid or classes for divs?

Comment: I think you're meant to solve this with a repeating generated `background-image` - I'm thinking it can be done with 4x `radial-gradient` background-image layers with hard gradient cutoffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do methods in this post help? [Pure CSS Chessboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114520/pure-css-chessboard-with-div-no-classes-or-ids-is-it-possible)

Adapting to this case, the selectors will be

```
  div:nth-child(8n+1),
  div:nth-child(8n+3),
  div:nth-child(8n+6),
  div:nth-child(8n+8) {
    background: #F09462;
  }
```

This is scalable even if you add more rows. For each 2 columns added, you have to add another line of selectors using the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even use multiple divs, just two background layers.

```css
html {
  --a: 5em;
  --b: calc(2*var(--a));
  --p: 60%;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(at 100% 100%, 
        #0000 calc(var(--p) - 1px), #62424c var(--p)) 
      0 0/ var(--a) var(--a), 
    repeating-conic-gradient(#ff8e55 0% 25%, #fad5af 0% 50%) 
      0 0/ var(--b) var(--b)
}
```