# Need flexible nth-child formula for infinite amount of posts

Tags: css

Any suggestion on a flexible nth-child formula that would allow me to recreate this layout display on the image below with an infinite amount of posts? As it is right now I'm doing it manually using nth-child(5), nth-child(8), etc. :

[image: image of float elements for nth-child question]

Comment: WHAT are you doing manually on 5 and 8? More info!

Comment: You can use loop. This thread might be a duplicate (though it's for 4 rows): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557662/jquery-how-to-alternate-an-odd-even-pattern-every-4-divs. Hope this helps.

Comment: What HTML are you using to mark up this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use multiple `nth-child` selectors that override previously styled elements.

Let's say this is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/* make all li elements green and 75% wide */
li {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px; /* for style */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* for style */
}

/* Make the 'even' ones 25% wide. */
li:nth-child(even) {
  width: 25%;
}

/* Make every 'fourth' one 25% wide and have a red background */
li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
}

/* Make every fourth one's (starting from 1) adjacent sibling 75% wide */
li:nth-child(4n+1) + li {
  width: 75%;
}

/* Make every fourth one (starting from 4) have a red background */
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: red;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ETahEQe/3/edit)**

Comment: This is total overkill.

Comment: The question asked how it could be done in CSS or CSS3.

Comment: Yes I know. My answer below has one css rule to change the appropriate elements to be "short".

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child()` accepts a formula with a variable `n` which presumably does exactly what you're asking, like writing an infinite amount of rules, solving the formula for every value of n=0, n=1, n=2, etc.

It seems you want red, green, green, red, red, green, green, red, red...

```
/* style all divs */
div.foo{
  /* green */
}
/* override styles on divs 0,3,6,9... */
div.foo:nth-child(4n-1),
div.foo:nth-child(4n){
  /* red */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

CSS logic has its place, but this is a job for javascript (or the server). As you build your posts, count them, then get an appropriate class name based on that number:

```
post_class = Math.round((post_num*.5)+.5) % 2 ? 'long' : 'short';
```

Add the class, and write your css accordingly. If you're building the html on the server, it's the same concept just do your rounding however is correct for your server-side language.

---

EDIT: Apparently I am not up to date enough on my CSS

```
div:nth-child(4n-2), div:nth-child(4n-1) {
   /* short styles */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6bAj/1/